# How to know if a vector is in a region created by 2 tangential line from one end of the vector to a circle?

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image: Example of what I'm taking about]

My question will be clearer looking at the picture.
The dash area is the area I want to know if the vector is inside of it or not. With the picture drawn out, the question seems to be trivial but I want to have a mathematical answer. My end goal is to have this problem solve through programming.

Let:

-The circle **O(x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>)** has a radius of **R**.

-The vector **u(a,b)** with the starting point of **(x<sub>u</sub>, y<sub>u</sub>)**

Comment: You need to specify what is given. Also, there are a lot of vectors that are equal to the one in the picture but have a different starting point. Do you care about that?

Comment: @Vasya Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to have a general answer for an arbitrary vector and arbitrary circle in XY plan. I have added some more details in the question.

Comment: Is it $\mathbf u$ that you wish to test? Is $(x_u,y_u)$ the cone’s apes?

Comment: @amd Yes, **u** is the vector I want to test and $(x_u, y_u)$ is the pointy end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Because triangles OAP and OBP are right,

$$x^2+R^2=OP^2, \mbox{or} $$
$$x=\sqrt{OP^2-R^2}$$

From properties of right triangles:

$$\frac{x}{OP}=\cos\frac{\alpha}{2},$$
where $\alpha$ denotes the angle BPA. Then

$$\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{OP^2-R^2}}{OP^2}$$

Because triangles BPO and APO have a side equal to R and share the side OP, then BPO and APO are identical and therefore OP cuts $\alpha$ into two equal angles $\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Now plot an arbitrary vector $\vec{PC}$ (the coordinates of C are assumed known). The vectors 
$$\frac{\vec{PC}}{PC} \mbox{  and  } \frac{\vec{PO}}{PO}$$
are unit vectors.

Then

$$\frac{\vec{PC}}{PC} \cdot \frac{\vec{PO}}{PO}=\cos\gamma.$$

If $\vec{PC}$ is between the two tangents,

$$\cos\gamma \ge \cos\frac{\alpha}{2},$$
because $\gamma \le \frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Therefore the condition for an arbitrary vector $\vec{PC}$ drawn from P and ending in C, to be between the two tangents, is

$$\frac{\vec{PC}}{PC} \cdot \frac{\vec{PO}}{PO} \ge \frac{\sqrt{OP^2-R^2}}{OP^2}$$.

To ensure the vector does not cross the circle, add these two conditions:

$$OC \ge R$$

and $PC \le PA$, that is

$$PC \le \sqrt{OP^2-R^2}$$

Comment: Good job, beautiful equation, easy to program. I haven't check out the math yet but looks good so far.